# How do I make a required radio input optional in Firefox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, firefox, validation

I'm trying to use [HTML5 Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Forms_in_HTML5#Constraint_Validation) in my forms to help users spot errors client-side before they submit (and obviously also doing server-side validation).

I have a situation where I need to *conditionally* make some fields required or optional based on what the user chooses in other fields. However, in Firefox, I'm having trouble making radio inputs **optional after they've been required** at some earlier point. I've tried both removing the required attribute and setting this.willValidate to false on these radio inputs, but Firefox still seems to think they're required no matter what I do.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rrud/fUcUn/

Does anyone have ideas for anything else I could try in JavaScript to tell Firefox to make these radios optional once they've been required?

My example works great in Chrome and Opera, and in Firefox all of the **non-radio** inputs behave as expected... so maybe this is just a bug in Firefox? I'm using Firefox 13.0 on Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's prop method: $.fn.prop

-> $('input').prop('required', true|false);

http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/fUcUn/12/

Comment: Yes!! This totally fixes my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Just add this to Your code**

> this.checked = false;

You code should look like

```
$(function() {
    $("#require").click(function() {
        $("input, textarea, select").attr('required', 'required');
    });
    $("#unrequire").click(function() {
        $("input, textarea, select").removeAttr('required').each(function() {
            this.willValidate = false;
            this.checked = false;
        });
    });
});
```

**Check this fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/ktfV6/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kabilan, but it looks like the radio inputs are still required in your fiddle (and the "Please select one of these options" message pops up next to them when trying to submit). Just to be clear: I'm looking for a way to make the radio inputs be optional AFTER they've been required at some earlier point.