# Firefox Issue: non-required radio-button gets flagged for valueMissing

Tags: javascript, firefox, validation

I have an issue perhaps very similar to 
[How do I make a required radio input optional in Firefox using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990861/how-do-i-make-a-required-radio-input-optional-in-firefox-using-javascript)

My example can be found here:
http://www.bradkent.com/?page=test/ff_radio

In a nutshell, I have an event viewer on a checkbox that toggles the visibility of a radio group.   The radio group is initially required, but when hidden, I change the radio inputs' required property to false  (node.required = false).  When the group is re-shown, the required property is changed back to true.
the dom inspector confirms that neither the required attribute or property is set.

So why is it requiring an option to be selected?
What am I doing wrong, or overlooking?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

well, I figured out the issue

node.required = true/false vs node.setAttribute('required',1); and node.removeAttribute('required');

the former had been done earlier in the code and at that point node.removeAttribute('required'); node.removeProp('required'); etc were all of no use in removing the required property (in Firefox)